# fatal runtime exception binary xml file reference?

Tags: inflate-exception

I get following fatal runtime exception (android 2.1) :

12-19 21:23:53.160: E/AndroidRuntime(279): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-19 21:23:53.160: E/AndroidRuntime(279): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class com.michaelnovakjr.numberpicker.NumberPicker

after having changed the namespace from com.michaelnovakjr to a different one.

I don't find any references to com.michaelnovakjr in the whole source code however anymore.

Who can tell me where exaclty to look?

I already did project clean, Eclipse restart, create new virtual Android device just in case anything is left behind/not rebuilt correctly.

The whole workspace consists of a project and a library, all now in namespace nl.computerhuys.TabNavUI. Since the fatal exception mentions 'main' I would assume the error would be in main.xml, of which there are two: one in the library:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World, ACTIVITY_ENTRY_NAME"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

and one in the project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World, NumberPickerSample"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

The line number 24 in the logcat errormessage obviously doesn't refer to either of these files. So how do I find out to what .xml file it does refer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found it.

There was actually another reference to the old namespace in dialog_number_picker.xml in the library. Found it by looking for all .xml files in the project (windows search), opening all of them in notepad++ and then doing a string search in all open files...

works fine now.